# IntelliJ doesn't recognize library although it is listed in project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Below is an example, when IntelliJ does not recognize SLF4J library, which is inluded into the project:

[image]

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: Try right-click on project --> Maven --> ReImport

Comment: And that `delegate` property should be of type List<Country> -- interfaces go on the left, implementations go on the right.

Comment: The list of libraries in the left hand panel can be deceiving... they represent the collection of all libs in your project, not broken down by scope. Your maven tab (on the RHS of IDE) has them broken down by scope. Most likely the logging API is missing from the scope you are working in (e.g. test vs main).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming its a maven project and you had included sl4j dependency in your `pom.xml`.

You can try doing below things.

1. Can you open your project structure by pressing *f4* key and see the Library section and check if sl4j jar is there, and if its not included there, then add it again. you can check the problem section as well and there should not be any error.
2. try deleting the **target** folder and run the `mvn clean package` command.

if it doesn't work then check if you have this jar in your .m2 folder with the correct version.if its not there then rerun the `mvn clean package` and see if it download the correct version of jar in .m2 folder.

let me know if this solve your issue or you have any questions.